# How does USB core associate the driver with specific HCI in LInux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to write a VHCI driver which is based on existing vhci_hcd in kernel source. My original thought was to write a USB driver to consume the VHCI code, which is bridged by USB core.

I was able to load the VHCI driver (based on exiting vhci_hcd) and saw the virtual hubs created from output of 'lsusb', and by default the deviceID/productID are already created by USB core. However I am not able to connect my USB driver to VHCI based on the deviceID/productID (not able to trigger probe() function in USB driver even though the IDs are matching).

Does anyone know if this is expected behavior? Does USB driver only connect to real HCI but not to VHCI?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by "consume the VHCI code"? Do you want to write an application that uses the VHCI user-space library to provide a virtual device under the VHCI root hub? Native C/C++ or .NET? If you used the library and it didn't work, how should we figure out what's wrong without seeing your driver code?

Comment: I want to write a USB driver to talk to VHCI instead of user-space program that talk to it by sysfs or ioctl). According to my understanding VHCI is similar to OHCI/UHCI code which are connected to real hardware. And USB drivers talk to USB core which eventually talk to OHCI/UHCI then to the hardware. I am able to see two virtual hubs (primary and shared) from lsusb output after loading vhci_hcd.ko. And deviceID/productID are already created by USB core (something like 1d6b:0003).  However my USB driver's probe() functions are not called even though IDs are matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prelimanary answer:

Let's try to sort out the assumptions, maybe we can clear things up.

> I want to write a USB driver to talk to VHCI instead of user-space program that talk to it by sysfs or ioctl)

What exactly do you mean by "USB driver"? A kernel driver that implements a specific device, like an USB camera? That would be an "USB gadget driver", and the kernel already has quite a few of those, so look at their code. If you want to test gadget drivers, you need `dummy_hdc`, which creates a virtual root hub that will contain all the devices represented by kernel gadget drivers.

The VHCI project is specifically made to allow **user space** USB drivers for (virtual) devices. If you don't want "a user-space program that talk to it by sysfs or ioctl", than VHCI is the wrong choice.

> According to my understanding VHCI is similar to OHCI/UHCI code which are connected to real hardware.

Yes, it provides a root hub; in so far it is similar.

> And USB drivers talk to USB core which eventually talk to OHCI/UHCI then to the hardware

You lost me here. Which "USB drivers" are you talking about? Do you mean kernel drivers that allow the computer and the user to interact with (real) USB devices? Like e.g. `usb_storage`, which makes USB mass storage devices visible as `/dev/sd*` etc.? These are completely independent from VHCI user-space drivers or USB gadget kernel drivers.

To be able to use these drivers, you must provide their counterpart in the form  of a real USB device on a real USB bus, or a simulated USB device as a kernel gadget driver via `dummy_hdc`, or a user-space driver via VHCI.

So if your real problem is: "I have this new USB device, which eventually should be real hardware, and I want to write a Linux kernel driver for it, but first I want to test it." Then you need **two** drivers: One is the kernel drivers you want to develop, the other is a virtual counerpart which simulates the not-yet existing device. You can do that in kernel space (gadget driver) or in user-space (VHCI).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification...  Indeed the 'VHCI' I was talking about is the piece that talks to hardware (via urb_enqueue()) and I wanted to know how should I talk to the 'VHCI' properly.  Sounds like the easy way is to do ioctl between userspace and VHCI.

Comment: VHCI provides a virtual root hub. It doesn't talk to real hardware. So I think a few things are still mixed up.

Comment: My 'VHCI' has to directly talk to the PCI driver that is already done for the hardware.  And I just figured out the reason my USB device driver couldn't hook to VHCI root hub was because USB core only scans PCI bus for matching deviceID/productID and obviously my VHCI root hub IDs are not in the list. I should  probably integrate the PCI driver into VHCI and call it something else so that I can write a USB device driver that can detect it and talk to VHCI via USB core or create a user program that directly talks to VHCI as you suggest. Does it sound right?

Comment: I still don't know what device your driver is for, because you never explained it. If the PCI device "for which the driver is already done" is an USB root hub, then you shouldn't use VHCI. Instead, the driver "that is already done" should be a kernel module that works similarly to ehci/xhci, whatever is more appropriate. If the PCI device is something else (an USB device which pretends to be a PCI device?), please explain.

Comment: Now that I have a better understanding I totally agree with you the best is to glue the PCI driver and HCI together so we can leverage USB device driver and USB core. Unfortunately the current design is not totally based on technical consideration. Basically the hardware I try to talk to has to be claimed by the PCI driver and the firmware can only be communicated to with a stripped version of USB protocol. So I am kind of building a kernel module talk to PCI driver that acts like VHCI. I was thinking of leveraging USB core earlier but looks like it's not a feasible method.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you have something in your hardware that acts like an USB device, and uses the USB protocol, except that USB protocol is transferred via some PCI hardware. Which means your PCI hardware acts as root hub connected to the other USB device. So I'd take the VHCI kernel driver source code, merge it with your PCI driver source code in such a way that the resulting kernel module claims the PCI device, registers a USB root hub with the kernel, and, if necessary, fakes the detection of your USB client behind the PCI device.

Comment: Then you need a second driver that makes whatever the USB client does available, unless the USB client implements a standard USB class for which there already a driver exists. (I still don't have enough information about your system).

Comment: Also, please have a look at [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and next time don't ask for Y ("how does USB core associate with VHCI"), but instead for X ("I have a PCI device which has hardware behind it that communicates via USB").

Comment: Got you. The info you provided is indeed very helpful, thank you very much.